# How to create a html file in django framework?

Tags: python, django, file

How to create multiple html files with dir and their file names using python's django framework.

Comment: Please include details on what you have tried so far, and more specific details about the problem you are encountering

Answer (score 0):

Django needs all the html files served in a folder:

step:1 make a folder in your root directory for instance call it "template"

step:2 go to setting.py your DIRS will be empty write:os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
```

thats how you server a html in django projects

if you want to add css files:
step 3: make a folder named static in the root directory and add all the css files,js files,plugins,imgs etc

step 4: go to settings and write this at the bottom:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')
```

step 5:in your html file write

```
{% load static %}
```

at the top

step6: for all the static files or css files or images write like this

```
src="{% static 'logo.jpg' %}"
href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">
```

then go to cmd and write the command python manage.py collectstatic.

and there you go!!! All set

Comment: that was amazing